# Is sharding already working in Ethereum?

Tags: evm, storage, nodes, sharding, state

I understand that `sharding` is a solution to prevent full nodes to be very expensive to run in terms of storage, as they store the state of every smart contract on chain (more information about this [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43101/where-is-contract-persistent-storage-stored)).

Is `sharding` already implemented in Ethereum? Where can I find more information about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently sharding is not implemented in Ethereum

- None of the current production nodes have any sharding support
- There is no clear technical plan how to implement sharding

Blockchains that support state sharding include

- [NEAR](https://near.org/papers/nightshade/)
- [MultiversX previously known as Elrond](https://docs.multiversx.com/technology/adaptive-state-sharding/)

Comment: Do you have a source that can support this answer for Ethereum? Thank you.

Comment: As an 100% authoritative answer, you can read GoEthereum source code and you will find there is no sharding https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/

Answer (score 2):

No, sharding has not been implemented in Ethereum
resources:

Ethereum's official website: https://ethereum.org
This website will provide you an introduction to Ethereum 2.0, including details on sharding.

Ethereum 2.0 specifications on GitHub: https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs
This repository has the technical specifications and documentation for Ethereum 2.0, includes the design and implementation of sharding as well.

Ethresear.ch: https://ethresear.ch
An online forum where Ethereum researchers and developers discuss various topics related to Ethereum, sharding and Ethereum 2.0.

Comment: This answer is not wrong - sharding is not implemented in Ethereum and does not have a clear technical plan how to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

"Polkadot is a sharded blockchain with heterogeneous shards. What sharding means in this context is splitting up the work that happens onto multiple sub-blockchains, known as parachains. What heterogeneous means in this context is that each blockchain has its own state-transition function that is purpose-built for a specific use-case. Different types of transactions will have different homes, which allows for specialized chains to serve their users most efficiently. Polkadot provides security and messaging functionality for all attached parachains."

https://polkadot.network/blog/polkadot-v1-0-sharding-and-economic-security

Answer (score -3):

> I understand that sharding is a solution...

There is no a common vision of what is *sharding* in the context of blockchain networks. Every project has its own vision of what is sharding, how sharding should be implemented and what set of problems it should solve.

> Is sharding already implemented in Ethereum?

No, it's not. When someone says "it's implemented into the roadmap of the prospective transition", it means "it's not implemented".

> Where can I find more information about it?

You can find a lot of information on the subject. However, you should keep in mind that this information is incomplete and not finalised.